# Python lettuce test results in XML

Tags: python, lettuce

I'm trying to get an xml report of the results of my behavior tests running in the lettuce framework. According the --help for lettuce, you should use the switch --with-xunit. I've done that (and also used --xunit-file) but no report is generated. I tried reinstalling lettuce but still no luck. How can I get it to generate this report?

Comment: You'd be better asking this on the Lettuce users' mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually something simple: the folder the tests were running in were owned by root so I needed to run the tests with sudo in order for it to generate the report.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is really late, but I made a boilerplate project for lettuce and python (and jenkins).

This is how I solved it:
[have coverage talk to lettuce](https://github.com/stephas/jenkins-lettuce/blob/master/tests/jenkins.sh#L17)

If you like an example, you are welcome to poke around here:
https://github.com/stephas/jenkins-lettuce